# Creating a Data Reader from a C# Object

Tags: c#, class, ado.net

I am having trouble with the following line:

```
MySqlDataReader DataReader = objDatabase.SetCommandType("GetRaceLevels").ExecuteReader();
```

It keeps returning the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Connection must be valid and open.'

```
private void RegisterForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HideMe();
            MoveMe(-180);

            MySqlConnection myConnection = objDatabase.GetConnection(); //must save the object based connection to a local variable for some reason.

            myConnection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader DataReader = objDatabase.SetCommandType("GetRaceLevels").ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                while (DataReader.Read())
                {
                    cboRunnerTypes.Items.Add(DataReader[1]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Critical error!");
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

I have tested the connection, it does work just fine, and it works during my login process.

The only other thing is this whole process utilises my clsDatabase class, that is where `MySqlDataReader DataReader = objDatabase.SetCommandType("GetRaceLevels").ExecuteReader();` comes from.

This is the function on the clsDatabse class:

```
public MySqlCommand SetCommandType(string sProcedureName)
        {
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sProcedureName, GetConnection()); //I think the problem is here, how am I fixing it though?
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            return myCommand;
        }
```

I hope this all makes sense and I am not being extremely thick. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: The class:

```
class clsDatabase
    {
        private const string conString = "server = ; database = ; user = ; password = ; charset = utf8";
        public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(conString);
            return myConnection;
        }

        public void EmailCommandCaller(MySqlCommand myCommand, string sEmail, string sContent)
        {
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(sEmail, sContent);
        }

        public void LoginCommandCaller(MySqlCommand myCommand, string sEmail, string sPassword, string sEmailContent, string sPasswordConetnt)
        {
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(sEmail, sEmailContent);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(sPassword, sPasswordConetnt);
        }
        public MySqlCommand SetCommandType(string sProcedureName)
        {
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sProcedureName, GetConnection()); //I think the problem is here, how am I fixing it though?
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            return myCommand;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this code, what is `objDatabase`?

Comment: Those SQL/DB helper functions are almost always more trouble than they are worth.  Both `SetCommandType` and `RegisterForm_Load` are using `GetConnection()` which means the connection in one method is not the same as the connection you open.  Just type out the code to do what you need to do and "optomize" once you know ***all*** the related hazards

Comment: Does `GetConnection` return the same connection each time, or a new one each time?

Comment: @Amy objDatabase is an instance of clsDatabse (class).

Comment: @BerwynNagant That tells me nothing; we are aware it is a class.  What is that class?  Show us please.  We need to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: You're returning a new connection in `GetConnection`, so when you call `SetCommandType` it's not open

Comment: @Amy My apologies, please see above for edited post.

Comment: @Magnetron Could you elaborate? I don't get it.

Comment: The MySqlCommand returned by the SetCommandType has a Connection property. You need to open that connection. However I agree on the fact that those home made classes that try to hide ADO.NET core object are just a pain. At that point it is better to use a full tested ORM. Have you ever tried to use Dapper?

Comment: @BerwynNagant No problem.  I'm aware that it can be hard to know what is important.  `GetConnection` looks good; it's generally ill-advised to re-use connections, but you aren't doing that, so kudos.  Ňɏssa's point about your command not using the same connection as the main body of code is correct.

Comment: @Steve I have no idea what you just said, this is just a throwaway uni project. I am just a rookie :D

Comment: @Amy Yeah I tried to do a similar thing with MySqlConnection, found that I must save it to a new instance of myConnection or it wouldn't work. I guess I just have to type it out the long winded way. Let me give that a go.

Comment: @BerwynNagant Just keep in mind that, when it comes to databases, re-using things is generally ill-advised.  The connection pool operates in the background and takes care of "sharing" for you.  Every time you need a connection, create one and keep it open only as long as it is needed, then dispose of it.

Comment: Thank you everyone! You guys are pretty insane! -in a good way ofc-

Comment: @BerwynNagant would be a good idea to tag this question also with [Ado.Net].  As that is the most relevant tag for this question.

Comment: @JimReineri No idea what that means but sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call `GetConnection()` you're getting a brand new one. A new connection starts closed. Now, look at your `SetCommandType` method. It's instancianting a new MySqlCommand with a brand new connection, which is closed. You could open the connection in the method, but that is error prone, as you would end up with no means to close the connection afterward. Instead, instantiate the connection where you want to use it. Also, use `using` statements for better `IDisposable` handling.

```
private void RegisterForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideMe();
    MoveMe(-180);
    using(MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(conString)){
        myConnection.Open();
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("GetRaceLevels", myConnection); 
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using(MySqlDataReader DataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()){
            try
            {
                while (DataReader.Read())
                {
                    cboRunnerTypes.Items.Add(DataReader[1]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Critical error!");
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cheers chief that worked! only thing is `using(MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(conString)){
        myConnection.Open();`
I don't have conString available so I just stuck with: `MySqlConnection myConnection = objDatabase.GetConnection();`

Comment: @BerwynNagant Yeah, in that specifically place (as a substitute for `new MySqlConnection(conString)`) you could maintain, but avoid using it in any other place.